# C# results of the division are not accurate after decimal point

Tags: c#, matlab, math, floating-point, double

I'm doing a porting of a matlab project in C#,
this snippet of matlab code fills griglia with decimal like 0.025, 0.075, 0.325

```
for xgriglia=x1+incxy/2:incxy:x2
        
        for ygriglia=y1+incxy/2:incxy:y2
            
            contagriglia=contagriglia+1;
            griglia(contagriglia,1)=xgriglia;
            griglia(contagriglia,2)=ygriglia;
            
            
        end
    end
```

I translated it in C# like so, (variables are all double)

```
for (var xgriglia = x1 + incxy / 2; xgriglia <= x2; xgriglia += incxy)
{
 for (var ygriglia = y1 + incxy / 2; ygriglia <= y2; ygriglia += incxy)
 {
  contagriglia++;
  griglia0[contagriglia - 1] = xgriglia;
  griglia1[contagriglia - 1] = ygriglia;
 }
}
```

but the results in griglia0 and gliglia1 are like: 0.075000000000000011, 0.32499999999999996, 0.37499999999999994

what is the cause of this? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Please provide types of variables and rename if you can because they're extremely difficult to process mentally LOL

Comment: Matlab is probably rounding the output so you don't see the imprecise nature of floating point arithmetic.  This question may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate. You can "fix" it by formatting it to (say) 3 decimal places when displaying the numbers.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Added that one too

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary variables are all double